# Select alternatives onClick

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, class

I'm making a javascript game in which it's shown a clock and the user must select the correct alternative for the given time shown in the clock.

I want the user to be able to select an alternative and if correct its backround to turn green and if false turn orange.

```
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock()" id="alternative1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel nach drei</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock()" id="alternative2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">f&uuml;nf vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock()" id="alternative3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">zehn Minuten vor eins</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock()" id="alternative4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
```

My javascript code.

```
function correctClock() {
document.getElementById('alternative1').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
document.getElementById('alternative2').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
document.getElementById('alternative3').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
document.getElementById('alternative4').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel nach drei</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">f&uuml;nf vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">zehn Minuten vor eins</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
```

Javascript

```
function correctClock(clickedButton) {
    var correct_answer = "alternative1";
    if (clickedButton.id == correct_answer) {
        document.getElementById('alternative1').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('alternative2').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock("alternative1")" id="alternative1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel nach drei</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock("alternative2")" id="alternative2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">f&uuml;nf vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock("alternative3")" id="alternative3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">zehn Minuten vor eins</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock("alternative4")" id="alternative4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
```

And check it in your callback:

```
function correctClock() {
if ("alternative1") {
    document.getElementById('alternative1').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
}
else if ("alternative2") {
    document.getElementById('alternative2').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
}
else if ("alternative3") {
    document.getElementById('alternative3').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
}
else {
    document.getElementById('alternative4').removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should pass the clicked element by passing 'this' as a parameter to the function correctClock

```
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel nach drei</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">f&uuml;nf vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">zehn Minuten vor eins</button>
<button type="button" onclick="correctClock(this)" id="alternative4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Viertel vor zw&ouml;lf</button>
```

and then you need to add a condition, depending on the id of the element we got. Considering alternative2 is the correct answer...

```
function correctClock(element) {
element.id==='alternative2'?element.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success"):element.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-danger")
}
```

That's it !

Comment: I'm pretty sire this should work
here's a JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Visrozar/s7cvnoev/

Comment: When the user clicks on one alternative all the wrong ones should become red and the correct one green. Iregardless.

Comment: And your code works in JS fiddle but not on my website. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: It's identical to yours. I got it from your fiddle.

Comment: I actually wanted to see where you've written your JavaScript code. Maybe you've written it in the wrong place, that's why it isn't working ?

Are you getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: Yes. Uncaught TypeError: element.removeClass is not a function.

Comment: Check again if you've written the code correctly.
Have you added 'this' in HTML onclick ?
Is there any spelling mistakes ?
etc, etc